# Legality of travelling to continental Europe with codeine products?

Tags: france, health, drugs

So I regularly take Nurofen Plus (codeine phosphate/ibuprofen) and Codinex (codeine phopshate only) which is available OTC here in Ireland.

I'm planning a holiday for the summer in either Spain, Portugal, or France. I was wondering what is the legality of travelling with them. I would be bringing 20 to 30 tablets with me in total.

Comment: I don't know the legalese, but get a proper medical prescriptions, even if the drug is freely available.

Comment: Please add if *codeine phosphate* is considered **Non-narcotic** or **Narcotic**, since any answer will be based on that.

Answer (score 1):

[france](/questions/tagged/france)

[French Customs](https://www.douane.gouv.fr/fiche/private-individuals-carrying-medicinal-products-france) states :

> > From a country that is not a Schengen area member state
>
> - Principle: the quantity transported is compatible with personal therapeutic use.
> - Supporting document to produce for customs: the doctor’s prescription, **production of which is mandatory.**

Comment: Sounds like a huge overhead for common painkillers. Personally, I'd buy them in the destination country.

Comment: Codeine and opioids in France are **not** OTC @Johnnyjanko

Comment: You quoted portion applies only to **Narcotic drug or psychotropic substance** and not for **Non-narcotic and non-psychotropic medicinal products**. You should add that header to make it clearer.